# mapping multiple ldap groups mapped to a single role using Spring security

Tags: spring, grails

We have LDAP/Spring Security working together on the grails project. 
How can I achieve multiple ldap groups mapped to a single role using Spring security ?
Example : 
admins - [ADMINS , SUPERADMINS]
users - [VIEWERS , TESTERS]

Here we need to code based on the roles admins or users instead of ldap groups  ADMINS , SUPERADMINS , VIEWERS , TESTERS .

Any help is greatly appreciated?